# Compton dimming inactive doesn't work with terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, i3, compton

Running i3 on ubuntu, with compton (all recent installations).

I want to use compton to dim inactive windows. It is currently mostly working using `inactive-dim = 0.2` just fine. The problem is that when I run a couple of terminals on the same screen, they're either all dim or all bright - it doesn't dim the terminals that aren't active.

I imagine this has something to do with how compton figures out if something is active or not - I can run multiple chrome windows or atom windows or whatever, and those work just fine. Any advice about configuring the terminal launcher? (currently just using i3-sensible-terminal which is launching gnome-terminal).

Comment: for the time being, I've just switched to rxvt instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your `compton.conf` (also works for picom):

```
detect-transient = false
detect-client-leader = false
```

From `man compton`'s entries for the equivalent inline options:

> ```
>   --detect-transient
>       Use WM_TRANSIENT_FOR to group windows, and consider windows
>       in the same group focused at the same time.
>
>   --detect-client-leader
>       Use WM_CLIENT_LEADER to group windows, and consider windows
>       in the same group focused at the same time.
>       WM_TRANSIENT_FOR has higher priority if --detect-transient
>       is enabled, too.
> ```